# Is it possible to convert an HTML file into QR code?

Tags: html, browser, qr-code

I have an HTML file that I wanted to convert into a QR code so that when a user scans it the website will load up (the website does not have a domain it is just an HTML file). I wanted the QR code scanner to treat it as a website and run it on the browser.

PS. The user shouldn't have the HTML file, the file shall be sent to the user and temporarily stored inside the phone's ram after scanning it.

Is it possible? And how do I do it?

Comment: Theoretically you should have been able to produce a [data:URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) of your page, but none of the browsers on my mobile will allow opening one from their QR reader... [If you want to try.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHAv6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options that you can explore for distributing your HTML. You don't necessarily need a domain. All you need it a hosting service. You can use e.g.: Amazon's S3.

You can explore from among following options:

1. any blob storage (e.g.: s3)
2. gitHub Pages (https://pages.github.com/)
3. heroku (free)

Once you have a URL that renders your HTML, it's just a matter of creating a QR code using your URL as the input.

For that, you can look into numerous free QR code generators online.
E.g.: https://me-qr.com

Answer (score 1):

Only way you could do this would be to upload the file to a file sharing service. Make a QR code with that link. Have user download index.html and then run. Would make way more sense to just get a domain.